# Glue Job to union dataframes using pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm basically trying to update/add rows from one DF to another. Here is my code:

```
# S3
import boto3

# SOURCE
source_table = "someDynamoDbtable"
source_s3 = "s://mybucket/folder/"

# DESTINATION
destination_bucket = "s3://destination-bucket"

#Select which attributes to update/add
params = ['attributeD', 'attributeF', 'AttributeG']

#spark wrapper
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

newData = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type = "dynamodb", connection_options = {"tableName": source_table})
newValues = newData.select_fields(params)
newDF = newValues.toDF()

oldData = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="s3", connection_options={"paths": [source_s3]}, format="orc", format_options={}, transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame")
oldDataValues = oldData.drop_fields(params)
oldDF = oldDataValues.toDF()

#makes a union of the dataframes
rebuildData = oldDF.union(newDF)
#error happens here
readyData = DynamicFrame.fromDF(rebuildData, glueContext, "readyData")

#writes new data to s3 destination, into orc files, while partitioning
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = readyData, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": destination_bucket}, format = "orc", partitionBy=['partition_year', 'partition_month', 'partition_day'])
```

The error I get is:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax on line readyData = ...

So far I've got no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that `rebuildData = oldDF.union(newData)` worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so I figured that for what I need to do would be better to use an OUTER JOIN. 
Let me explain:

- I load two dataframes, where one drops the fields that we want to update.
- The second one selects just those fields, so both would not have duplicate rows/columns.
- Instead of union, which would just add rows, we use outer(or full) join. This add all the data from my dataframes without duplicates.

Now my logic may be flawed, but so far it is working okay for me. If anyone is looking for a similar solution you are welcome to it.
My changed code:

```
rebuildData = oldDF.join(newData, 'id', 'outer')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are performing the union operation between a dataframe and a dynamicframe.

This creates a dynamicframe named **newData** and a dataframe named **newDF**:

```
newData = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type = "dynamodb", connection_options = {"tableName": source_table})
newValues = newData.select_fields(params)
newDF = newValues.toDF()
```

This creates a dynamicframe named **oldData** and  a dataframe named **oldDF** :

```
oldData = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="s3", connection_options={"paths": [source_s3]}, format="orc", format_options={}, transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame")
oldDataValues = oldData.drop_fields(params)
oldDF = oldDataValues.toDF()
```

And you are performing the union operation on above two entities as below :

```
rebuildData = oldDF.union(newData)
```

which should be :

```
rebuildData = oldDF.union(newDF)
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed, but that seems to be a misspelling when copying my code. This isn't the problem, unfortunately :(

Comment: could you add the output for rebuildData.show and detailed stack trace?